# C: why after fork() child block is not running?

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, child-process

I'm studying how fork() actually works so my code below has no purpose other than spawning new processes with fork() and see them die randomly. So:

1. I put my fork() in a for loop (to run twice for now) to see more than one child be created, and to my surprised it seems that the second Child has a parent that was not the same parent as the first child. So, if my initial PID was 1000, the two child created would be 1002 (child of 1000) and 1003 (child of 1001???). I didn't understand what happened that a parent was created. [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9seb8hddeK4&list=PLtIghEzKnLLN9nnwF5y-zFKJyqa91yPRn&index=18&t=701s) explained but I can't say I fully understood.
2. To try and find out what was going on, I printed my parent (and child) processes with their PID, but if I declare a char for my parent, my child won't run the function. I explain what I mean in my code between `<<< >>>`.

So, can anyone help me understand my 1st point, and identify why 2 is happening?

Full code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

const int PASS = 5;
const int RANDLIMIT = 5;
const int FORKNUMBER = 2;
int i = 0;

void doSomeWork(char *who);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Just started, I am: %d\n", (int) getpid());
  int j;
  pid_t pid;

  for (j=0; j < FORKNUMBER; j++)
    pid = fork();

  printf("fork returned: %d\n", (int) pid);
  srand((int) pid + rand());

  if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork failed");
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    char * childPid;
    char * childName;
    sprintf(childPid, "%d", (int) getpid());
    childName = (char *) malloc(strlen("Child - ") + strlen(childPid) + 1 );
    strcpy(childName, "Child - ");
    strcat(childName, childPid);
    doSomeWork(childName);
    exit(0);
  }

  //<<< The malloc above for the child to send a parameter >>>
  //<<< to the function, works fine. But when I try to do  >>>
  //<<< the same for my parent, the simple declaration of a>>>
  //<<< char below, makes the child block (the if PID==0)  >>>
  //<<< not run. The 3 lines commented below were an       >>>
  //<<< attempt to understand what was preventing the child>>>
  //<<< block from running. Now, if the parent calls the   >>>
  //<<< function with a string not declared before, the    >>>
  //<<< child block runs fine.>>>

  //char parentName[strlen("Parent") + 1];
  //strcpy(parentName, "Parent");
  //doSomeWork(parentName);
  doSomeWork("Parent");
  //wait(NULL);
  return(0);
}

void doSomeWork(char *who)
{
  int control = 0;
  for(; i < PASS; i++){
    sleep(rand() % RANDLIMIT);
    printf("%s: Done pass #%d, my parent = %d\n", who, i, getppid());

    if (control == 0)
    {
      char childWord[6];
      strncpy(childWord, who, 5);

      if (strcmp(childWord, "Child") == 0 && (int) getppid() == 1 )
      {
        control = 1;
        printf("%s: became orphan at #%d\n", who, i);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s: exiting...\n", who);
}
```

EDIT:

For 1, I created a function like below:

```
int nbDigits(int number)
{
  int i=0;
  for(; number > 10; i++)
  {
    number /= 10;
  }
  return ++i;
}
```

Now instead of declaring a pointer to a char like this, `char * childPid;` I declared a char array like this `char childPid[nbDigits(getpid()) + 1];` and everything worked like a charm.

Check out Joseph's suggestion below using `asprintf()`, seems neat.

Comment: man page is not very clear as it is for all printf family. But it says it writes to the character string, which is the first parameter.

Comment: The childPid string, which I indicated with the pointer above

Comment: there is a pointer to a string. Do you mean this is wrong?

Comment: I meant it’s a pointer to a char. No?

Comment: Its **type** is pointer to char. What string does it point to?

Comment: you're totally right... I reviewed my C books and went over pointers again... hadn't done it since college. I ended up creating a function which returns me the number of digits in an int, this way I can declare a char array with the right amount of digits, plus 1. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, forgot to ask, maybe `sprintf` was writing my string to that pointer without a `\0` at the end and that was messing up the memory?

Comment: Now, after my change, it writes to childPid which is a string now, and not a pointer anymore. Before it was writing to a pointer that was leading nowhere I think?

Comment: The pointer was uninitialized. You formally can't even **read** its value as it does *not* have a well defined value (not even null).

Comment: Yep. That’s why I’m not using a pointer anymore. I got the logic wrong before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't call `fork()` in a loop but only check what it returns at the end of the loop if you want your program to work. When you do so, you're starting an exponential number of child processes, and each one thinks it's "the parent" as long as it was the parent of its final fork(). Move your test of `pid` to inside the loop.
2. ```
   char * childPid;
   sprintf(childPid, /* ... */);
   ```

   That's going to clobber some random memory. You need to point `childPid` to something before you `sprintf` to it, or replace `sprintf` with something like [`asprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) that will allocate itself.

Comment: right... my printf with pid inside the loop allowed me to see all the returns. Now just the other part (2) remains with no explanation, thanks.

Comment: @Adriano_epifas I edited in an answer to the other part.

Comment: oh, I guess asprintf would've solved my problem, but I ended up creating a function which will return me the number of digits in an int, so I can declare char myString[<returned value> + 1]. I edited my question with it and am suggesting your approach too. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you run `fork()` any child process will start its execution from there.

> Fork system call use for creates a new process, which is called child
>   process, which runs concurrently with process (which process called
>   system call fork) and this process is called parent process. After a
>   new child process created, both processes will execute the next
>   instruction following the fork() system call. [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/)

Thus, when your first iteration happens `(i=0)` there will be a new process, with a new `pid`, and then, both parent and this child process will call the next iteration `(i=1)` and create a new child for each one with two more new `pid`. In the end, you will have 4 different `pid`.

**Example**

1. Parent process `pid=1000`
2. `i = 0`, creates `pid=1001`, now you have both `1000` and `1001`
3. `i = 1`, creates a child from `1001` -> `1002` and a child from `1000` again, `1003`.

In the end you have `1000`, `1001`, `1002` and `1003` and all of these four processes will run the following instruction which is the `printf`.

Comment: very nice explanation miguel. One thing about this still bugs me though. I don't see the output of my printf for the 1st child created (PID 1002), that is the "fork returned:" part. Why is that?

Comment: Just quick compiled your example (until the `printf`) and its actually working fine. There are four `fork returned` where two have a `pid` number (the parent and the second child-parent`, and other two with `0` for both created children. Remember that in the child of the `fork()` call, it will return `0`.

Comment: Actually I moved the `printf` inside the loop, as suggested by Joseph above and now I can see this `1002` return.